# Excel VBA Text to Columns Backwards with maximum # of columns

Tags: vba, excel

```
Apples, Oranges, Strawberries, Pears, Almonds, Peanuts, Peaches
```

I would like to find "," from backwards (instrrev) and perform something similar to text to columns function in Excel, which would

```
#1 > Apples, Oranges
#2 > Apples | Oranges
```

perform action that takes #1 to #2.

However, I would like to have maximum columns of 5 (split into 5 pieces and the split-base character searched from backwards)

so that the top example would result in:

```
Apples, Oranges, Strawberries | Pears | Almonds | Peanuts | Peaches
```

- Please keep in mind that it is possible for the text to have no commas, so I need to check if they exists first

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you say the text can have no commas do you mean that it would just be one word/phrase that would go in a column on its own? Or that you could have multiple words but with no commas. i.e. Apples Oranges Strawberries

Comment: @JpadLimited Sorry for the confusion, I mean there can be multiple words but with no commas. In actual case, they are sentences and the delimiter is period. It is a product description that is in one cell, which needs to be divided into 5 columns total, to be used as a bullet-point like feature. Thus even when there are more than 5 sentences, I need to limit the columns to 5. Also, there may be sentences with no periods.

Comment: ok, I think the answer I just posted should get you going. Let me know if you have more questions - if this helps you please mark as answer/upvote. Thanks

Comment: What did YOU do, and where do you have a programming error ? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour, specially the part `Ask about...`  and `Don't ask about...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, by putting your example text in a cell, selecting that cell and then running the below. You will need to test this, and possibly handle some scenarios yourself - but this code should get you going and works on your example.

```
Sub SplitIntoColumns()
Dim intMaxCols          As Integer
Dim intCommaFoundPos    As Integer
Dim intNumCommasFound   As Integer
Dim strTextToCheck      As String
Dim strFoundText        As String
Dim intRowToWriteTo     As Integer
Dim intColToWriteTo     As Integer

    'this should be max num of columns you want -1
    intMaxCols = 4

    'just putting the text into the activecell and running on that
strTextToCheck = ActiveCell

'row to write output to
intRowToWriteTo = 10

'column to write output to - it will go backwards from here
intColToWriteTo = 10

'find the comma
intCommaFoundPos = InStrRev(strTextToCheck, ",")

'if there is a comma
If intCommaFoundPos > 0 Then

    'loop until you have looped the max columns number of times, or until there are no commas left in the string
    Do Until (intNumCommasFound = intMaxCols) Or intCommaFoundPos = 0

        'get comma position
        intCommaFoundPos = InStrRev(strTextToCheck, ",")

        'if there is still a comma
        If intCommaFoundPos > 0 Then

            'keep track of the number found
            intNumCommasFound = intNumCommasFound + 1

            'take everything to right of comma
            strFoundText = Trim(Mid(strTextToCheck, intCommaFoundPos + 1, Len(strTextToCheck)))

            'write to sheet, adjust next column number
             ActiveSheet.Cells(intRowToWriteTo, intColToWriteTo) = strFoundText
            intColToWriteTo = intColToWriteTo - 1

            'change the text to check to not include the word just found
            strTextToCheck = Left(strTextToCheck, intCommaFoundPos - 1)

        End If

    Loop

    'if there is any text left, write to sheet
    If Len(strTextToCheck) > 0 Then ActiveSheet.Cells(intRowToWriteTo, intColToWriteTo) = strTextToCheck

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: @1tntla, if you have lots of data, this will work slow. If you ask me, I will build a faster sollution for your

Comment: It runs on 10,000 rows of data in under 1 second. That is not to say it could not be more efficient, but it is only intended to give the poster a starting point.

Comment: @JpadLimited Thank you for the answer. I got it working, but without the second if statement that checks for a comma. Could you look into that before I select this as an answer? Thanks =]

Comment: What is the problem with the second if statement? It works for me

Comment: @JpadLimited Nothing wrong, just couldn't figure out why it was necessary. I think it's unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement it in formula:

`=IF(LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))<5,SUBSTITUTE(A3,",","|"),REPLACE(A3,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A3,",","@",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))-4))+1,LEN(A3),SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A3,",","@",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",""))-4))+1,LEN(A3)),",","|")))`

with the string in A3

How it works:

1. Find out the number of "," in the string by subtracting length of comma-less string from full string.
2. if less than 5 commas then substitute all "," with "|"
3. if equal to or more than 5 commas then, find the character position of the 5th comma from right,and replace the string after that character position with the substituted string.